# Can my landlord raise my rent for switching to a month-to-month lease?

Tags: united-states, rental-property, california, rent, landlord

When I first rented my apartment in Los Angeles 3 years ago, it was not rent-controlled. It had a clause saying my rent would increase by $600 per month if I went month-to-month, with a $600 fee to begin. I had to give 60 days notice to move out, but otherwise could renew a 12 month lease. They raised my rent every year and this year is the first year I have rent control. They are raising my rent the maximum allowable (3%).

They want me to sign another 12 month lease, but I would prefer month-to-month, if possible. My question is, since my lease says the month-to-month rate is higher, if I switch to month-to-month, is the increase (greater than 3%) legally enforceable? Would this be considered a new lease? My understanding is that all leases default to month-to-month at the same rate in a rent controlled building.

Comment: Not sure how rent-control would affect the month to month rate. Generally it's higher, but I don't know about rent-controlled areas so i'll butt out. Though, I'd really recommend you just get out of the building and do perhaps an AirBnB rental or something cheap until you find another place. $600/month more is ridiculous for month to month rate hike

Comment: This seems like more of a legal question than a personal finance question.  Also, it will depend on the specific rent control laws where you live.

Comment: In the US, month to month rentals are considered riskier, so higher rental rates are the norm

Comment: month-to-month is ***hugely*** more expensive than a 12 month lease.